# Redux Selector for normalized state

Tags: reactjs, redux, selector, reselect

I need help in creating the selectors for the state which is normalized based on the documentation from [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

**State**

```
{
    "entities": {
        "people": {
            "byId": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "Test User 1",
                    "classes": ["class1", "class2"],
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "Test User 2",
                    "classes": ["class2", "class3"],
                    "isSelected": false
                },
                "3": {
                    "name": "Test User 3",
                    "classes": ["class4"],
                    "isSelected": false
                }
            },
            "allIds": ["1", "2", "3"]
        },
        "classes": {
            "byId": {
                "class1": {
                    "name": "Class 1",
                    "courses": ["course1", "course2"]
                },
                "class2": {
                    "name": "Class 2",
                    "courses": ["course2"]
                },
                "class3": {
                    "name": "Class 3",
                    "courses": ["course1", "course3"]
                }
            },
            "allIds": ["class1", "class2", "class3"]
        },
        "courses": {
            "byId": {
                "course1": {
                    "name": "Course 1"
                },
                "course2": {
                    "name": "Course 2"
                },
                "course3": {
                    "name": "Course 3"
                }
            },
            "allIds": ["course1", "course2", "course3"]
        }
    }
}
```

On every people's profile, I want to display the associated classes and courses. I am unable to create selectors to get access to this information.

**People's Selector**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getPeopleDetails = createSelector(
    state => state.entities.people,
    (people) => people.allIds.reduce(
        (acc, cV) => {  
            if(people.byId[cV].isSelected) acc.push(people.byId[cV]); return acc; 
        }, [])
);

export default {
    getPeopleDetails
}
```

Since `createSelector` doesn't accept any parameter. For my slice in state for `courses`; how can I create a selector where to get information for the current selected people's profile?

Should I create a junction table for to depict the relationship between the entities?

*(I am very new to react/redux)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one by create another state slice called `ui`. In that slice, I manage the selected object IDs.

The components are rendered when there is a value in the selected Id for a particular component. Every component has a `if` condition which checks the the `ui` slice has the selected IDs populated.

[image: React Design]

For example,

```
{
    "ui": {
        "personSelectedId": ["1"],
        "classSelectedId": ["class1", "class2"],
        "courseSelectedId": ["course1", "course2"],
    }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector can take props as well as state. Then you can use it as an argument to the selector:

```
const getPerson = (state, props) =>
  state.entities.people.byId[props.id];

const getPersonDetails = createSelector(
  getPerson,
  state => state.entities.classes,
  (person, classes) => {
    // loop through classes, etc..
    // return whatever
  }
);
```

Comment: Hello @Austin, Thanks for the reply. My application is following the principles as [redux-ducks](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be).

`Person` selector shouldn't query the state slice which it isn't responsible for, correct?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, but you might query it using a selector exposed by the relative duck/branch.